# JsTree multitree cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

Hello guys I use jstree and I have multiple tree in the same page. I have two problems:

1) I want cookies in order to distinguish which nodes are open in each tree. I try to implement this functionality using prefix but unfortunately:

```
"cookies" : { "cookie_options" : { "prefix" : "home" } },
```

does not work since only the last opened node is re-opened after refresh.

2) I do not want to be able to create new root nodes.I only want to be able to create files or transfer files into my root directory.

I am trying to achieve that using:

```
"types" : {
            "types" : {
                // The default type
                "default" : {
                    "valid_children" : "none",
                    "icon" : {
                        "image" : "./file.png"
                    }
                },
                // The `folder` type
                "folder" : {
                    "valid_children" : [ "default", "folder", "file" ],
                    "icon" : {
                        "image" : "./folder.png"
                    }
                },
                // The `drive` nodes 
                "drive" : {
                    // can have files and folders inside, but NOT other `drive` nodes
                    "valid_children" : [ "default", "folder" ],
                    "icon" : {
                        "image" : "./root.png"
                    },
                    // those prevent the functions with the same name to be used on `drive` nodes
                    // internally the `before` event is used
                    "start_drag" : false,
                    "move_node" : false,
                    "delete_node" : false,
                    "remove" : false
                }
            }
        },
```

but I am still able to post files into my root directory. Should I create another `<li>` without `rel=drive` above the root directory?

Thanks.

Comment: ad 1) I think that it is side effect of using cookies plugin...

Comment: Do you know how to fix it? I have already fixed the second one..

Comment: Did you manage to get multiple cookies for different trees? I'm searching for the same problem!

Answer (score 2):

The solution for cookies in multiple trees:

```
.
.
"cookies": {
  "save_selected": "node_selected_" + tree_id
  "save_opened": "node_opened_" + tree_id
},
.
.
```

There is no such option as "prefix". "save_selected" and "save_opened" take either a string or false. By providing different tree_id you effectively use different cookies for each tree.

Comment: miss comma after the first tree_id (between two params)